# Python substring a dataframe column not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using a piece of code that looks like this

```
output_df['test'] = str(output_df['givencolumn'].str[0:2])
```

And I cannot understand why .str[0:2] would return something like below in the test column on the Output_df.

[image: Output_df]

As simple as it looks like, I am not able to figure out where the mistake is happening. Kindly help me solving this without the sample file(confidential).

I am expecting my test column to look something like

```
Index  test
0      01
1      01
2      01
3      01
4      01
```

So, I figured out the problem now :-

This is working

```
output_df['test'] = output_df['givencolumn'].str[0:2]
```

This is not working :-

```
starting_position = 0
ending_position = 2

given_data[required_column_name] = given_data['givencolumn'].str[starting_position:ending_position]
```

my function :-

```
def build_columns(given_data,given_layout):
    for i in range(0, 2):
        required_column_name = str(given_layout.iloc[i][1])
        starting_position = int(given_layout.iloc[i][2])
        ending_position = int(given_layout.iloc[i][4])
        print(starting_position)
        print(ending_position)
        given_data[required_column_name] = str(output_df['givencolumn'])        
        given_data[required_column_name] = given_data['givencolumn'].str[1:2]
    return(given_data)
```

Comment: What is `print(output_df['givencolumn'].str[0:2].tolist())` ?

Comment: Can you tell what actually do you expect

Comment: @jezrael .tolist()) is returning a list of ['01',01',01',01'.........]

Comment: hmm, if use `output_df['test'] = output_df['givencolumn'].str[0:2]` same problem? If check `print(output_df['givencolumn'].tolist())` there are only strings?

Comment: @jezrael updated the question with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the str() call. It works like this:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'test': [
        '00',
        '012'
        '013',
        '02'
]})

df['test2']= df['test'].str[:2]
df
```

Not sure, why you call str() with the column. I guess this might be the problem, because what .str[:2] produces is not a string, but a series which consists of strings and thats what you should assign if you intend to assign a value that is depending on other row values (or just the index of the row). Probably this is a misundertanding. If you do something like pd.DataFrame['col']= scalarValue it assigns the value to the field in all rows. But generally you assign series. For esample if you have a numeric column, say this year's salary and you want to assign the salary of next year including a pay rise of 5%, then your code could look like

```
salrary_df['salary_2020']= salrary_df['salary_2019'] * 1.05
```

It could seeem, that pandas virtually executes this assignment for each line, but that's not how it is done. In fact it executes the right side, which produces a series and then assigns the series to the column (internally it might copy it to an array of multiple columns that share the same data type, to make processing more efficient).

Comment: For you `df['test2']= str(df['test'].str[:2])` not working? For me nice.

Comment: Updated the problem in the question.

Comment: It doesn't produce runtime errors, but I guess it is not what the poster intended, because it converts the series into a string using its __str__ method and assigns this same value to all rows. Right?

Comment: Btw, are you __really__ sure, that "given_data[required_column_name] = given_data['givencolumn'].str[starting_position:ending_position]" didn't give the same result? if so, than that would not be a problem in pandas, but the python interpreter would be buggy, because, what is passed to [] is the result of the preprocessing by the parser/interpreter and has nothing to do with pandas.